# How to send keypresses to a DirectX application?

Tags: c#, delphi, directx, windows-messages

I need to write a program in any programming language (preferably Delphi 7 / Delphi 10 / C#) that emulates pressing `1` every 10 seconds to a given process in Windows XP or Windows 7. Sending Windows messages, which worked for all the other applications I have tried, didn't work for this particular one and I am suspecting it is because it is using DirectX. Can this be done without overwriting `DX*.DLL` files? How?

Thank you,
Tom

EDIT: I've just tried using SendInput (in Delphi 7 on Windows XP with code from http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=220) and that doesn't work, either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've used [IO.DLL](http://www.geekhideout.com/iodll.shtml), which unfortunately doesn't work on 64-bit, but I'm still happy that about 90% of my target uses 32-bit.

Comment: Is there any way you could use this from C#?

Comment: @luvieere: Try this: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/csharp/call_dll.html and if everything fails, ask your question on StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

If the application don't process WM_CHAR/etc Windows Messages (XInput/DirectInput) your best bet is to make a dll to inject into the app overriding some of the functions cause those use directly the system resources to access the keyboard/mouse/gamepad. (really bad idea to use DirectInput/XInput for keyboard anyway :|)

Answer (score 0):

The application is probably using DirectInput or XInput. There is little you can do in this case because DirectInput works directly with the keyboard driver.